# Is it possible to extract dynamic values from the Response URL through JMeter before it appears in the Response?

Tags: jmeter

Please refer the image displayed on clicking the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lSD.png

Questions:

Is it possible to extract the highlighted values - Blazor ID and Timestamp in JMeter even when the response fails? (Since these values are unique, dynamic and change for each session - it fails on rerunning them)

Is it possible to create/record > amend > run JMeter scripts when we have such dynamic and unique values involved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extract them from URL using either [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or the [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter), just make sure to use the appropriate "Field to check", in your case most probably it will be `URL`

[image]

With regards to the "timestamp" - it can be generated using JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) if it is not present anywhere.

Comment: I have tried using the Regular Expression Extractor and URL, but the ID and timestamp are not getting extracted. Any advice on what I might have done wrong and the response fails? @Dmitri